# Perl: Search text file for keywords from array

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

How do I use keywords from an array in an regex to search a files.

I'm trying to look at a text file and see if and where the keywords appear. There are two files keywords.txt

```
keyword.txt
word1
word2
word3

filestosearchon.txt
a lot of words that go on and one and contain linebreaks and linebreaks (up to 100000   characters)
```

I would like to find the keyword and the position of the match. This works for one word but I am unable to figure out how to iterate the keywords on the regex.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# open profanity list
open(FILE, "keywords.txt") or die("Unable to open file");
@keywords = <FILE>; 
close(FILE);

# open text file
local $/=undef; 
open(txt, "filetosearchon.txt") or die("Unable to open file");
$txt = <txt>;

$regex = "keyword";


push @section,[length($`),length($&),$1]    
while ($txt =~ m/$regex/g);

foreach $element(@section)  
{
print (join(", ",@$element), $regex, "\n");    
}
```

How can I iterate the keywords from the array over this while loop to get the matched keywords and position?

Appreciate anyhelp. Thanks

Comment: If you only need to match whole words from keyword.txt against whole words in filestosearch.txt you might not needed regular expressions. I'd just create a hash with keywords as the keys and 1 as the value. Then attempt to look up each word in filestosearchon.txt in the hash. If the lookup succeeds, there is a match.

Comment: @BrianSwift: perhaps not the most efficient solution because it requires one pass over the string, per keyword. A finite automata approach (i.e. a regular expression) only needs one pass.

Comment: @Li-aung Yip: my approach only requires one pass through the input string/file parsing it into words and attempting to lookup each of those words in the hash which uses keywords as keys. A benefit of your approach is the keywords could be regular expression, not just fixed strings. However, using regexp may require syntax to only match  whole words so that `sex` doesn't match `misexplain`.

Comment: @BrianSwift: Whoops, slightly misread your proposed approach. I agree that it only takes one pass to add all the words to a hash, but OP also wants to know where matches occur (if they do.)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to just build a regex containing every word:

```
(alpha|bravo|charlie|delta|echo|foxtrot|...|zulu)
```

Perl's regex compiler is pretty smart and will smoosh this down as much as it can, so the regex will be more efficient than you think. [See this answer by Tom Christiansen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9297025/1191425). For example the following regex:

```
(cat|rat|sat|mat)
```

Will compile to:

```
(c|r|s|m)at
```

Which is efficient to run. This approach probably beats the "search for each keyword in turn" approach because it only needs to make one pass over the input string; the naive approach requires one pass per keyword you want to search for.

By the way; If you're building a profanity filter, as your sample code suggests, remember to account for intentional mis-spellings: 'pron', 'p0rn', etc. [Then there's the fun you can have with Unicode!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491890/is-there-a-list-of-characters-that-look-similar-to-english-letters)

Comment: My worry is that this regex containing every keyword is going to look super-cumbersome...

Answer (score 2):

Try `grep`:

```
@words = split(/\s+/, $txt);

for ($i = 0; $i < scalar(@words); ++$i) {
    print "word \#$i\n" if grep(/$words[$i]/, @keywords);
}
```

Would give you the word position in your text string where a keyword was found. This may or may not be more helpful than a character-based position.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is the output you expect, but something like this could be useful. I save keywords in a hash, read next file, split each line in words and search each one in the hash.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

die qq[Usage: perl $0 <keyword-file> <search-file>\n] unless @ARGV == 2;

open my $fh, q[<], shift or die $!;

my %keyword = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } <$fh>;

while ( <> ) {
        chomp;
        my @words = split;
        for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#words; $i++ ) {
                if ( $keyword{ $words[ $i ] } ) {
                        printf qq[Line: %4d\tWord position: %4d\tKeyword: %s\n], 
                                $., $i, $words[ $i ];
                }
        }
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl keyword.txt filetosearchon.txt
```

And output should be similar to this:

```
Line:    7      Word position:    7     Keyword: will
Line:    8      Word position:    8     Keyword: the
Line:    8      Word position:   10     Keyword: will
Line:   10      Word position:    4     Keyword: the
Line:   14      Word position:    1     Keyword: compile
Line:   18      Word position:    9     Keyword: the
Line:   20      Word position:    2     Keyword: the
Line:   20      Word position:    5     Keyword: the
Line:   22      Word position:    1     Keyword: the
Line:   22      Word position:   25     Keyword: the
```